# Lotus Notes Client crash ntdll.EtwEventEnabled

Tags: lotus-notes

Lotus Notes Client crashed for one of the user few days back. After that we had him install the Lotus Notes twice but the issue continues. PLease find the NSD below. It shows ntdll.EtwEventEnabled at the top of the stack trace and Access Violation as the error message but I am not able to find the resolution.

```
############################################################
### FATAL THREAD 1/6 [ NLNOTES:146c:17e0]
### FP=0x0012ef28, PC=0x774e224d, SP=0x0012eed8, stksize=80
### EAX=0x00000000, EBX=0xfffffffc, ECX=0x00000000, EDX=0x00000004
### ESI=0x01af05f8, EDI=0x01af05fc, CS=0x0000001b, SS=0x00000023
### DS=0x00000023, ES=0x00000023, FS=0x0000003b, GS=0x00000000 Flags=0x00010213
Exception code: c0000005 (ACCESS_VIOLATION)
############################################################
 [ 1] 0x774e224d ntdll.EtwEventEnabled+458 (0,0,1af05f8,1af0428)
 [ 2] 0x774e215c ntdll.EtwEventEnabled+217 (1af05f8,3,0,3b88fa0)
@[ 3] 0x10010b6d nstclientu._STCRegisterForStatusNotifications@8+93 (1af0428,701ca,3b9c880,12efa4)
@[ 4] 0x61632beb nnotesws._DeskIMRegisterForStatusNotifications@8+75 (1af0428,701ca,12f624,3b9c880)
@[ 5] 0x61801fce nnotesws.CLineView::CheckForSametimeColumn+254 (4,61b5c808,3ba9a80,0)
@[ 6] 0x612a7734 nnotesws.CLineView::ProcessMessage+7124 (3b9c880,701ca,73d,0)
@[ 7] 0x6129ea41 nnotesws.CViewSubprogram::SubMessageProc+497 (3ba9a80,73d,0,0)
@[ 8] 0x611848f4 nnotesws._MainWndProc@16+6932 (701ca,73d,0,0)
 [ 9] 0x7762c4e7 USER32.gapfnScSendMessage+463 (61182de0,701ca,73d,0)
 [10] 0x7762c5e7 USER32.gapfnScSendMessage+719 (0,61182de0,701ca,73d)
 [11] 0x7762cc19 USER32.gapfnScSendMessage+2305 (61182de0,0,12f7a8,61221998)
 [12] 0x7762cc70 USER32.DispatchMessageW+15 (12f788,612216d0,61180000,1)
@[13] 0x61221998 nnotesws._NEMMainLoop@4+712 (401000,0,1f224c,0)
@[14] 0x0040156d NLNOTES._WinMain@16+1389 (400000,0,1f224c,1)
@[15] 0x00401dfa NLNOTES._WinMainCRTStartup+308 (7ffd3000,12ffd4,7751377b,7ffd3000)
 [16] 0x75cded6c kernel32.BaseThreadInitThunk+18 (7ffd3000,77764db1,0,0)
 [17] 0x7751377b ntdll.RtlInitializeExceptionChain+239 (401cc6,7ffd3000,0,0)
 [18] 0x7751374e ntdll.RtlInitializeExceptionChain+194 (401cc6,7ffd3000,0,78746341)

Generated Messages:

   INFO (0): Using PSAPI DLL
   INFO (0): Found 2 Notes processes, matched 2
   INFO (0): Starting Debugger
   INFO (0): Walk mem for process NLNOTES (146c)
   INFO (0): Walk mem for process ntaskldr (1040)
   INFO (0): terminated process [ NLNOTES:146c]
   INFO (0): terminated process [ntaskldr:1040]
   INFO (0): Deleting pid.nbf
   WARNING (3): can't get process 342622208 status
   WARNING (0): Debugger still attached to 2 processes

   ERROR (4): can't attach to process [       ?:0004] - (5) Access is denied.

   ERROR (0): exception(0): thread aec got system exception: ACCESS_VIOLATION (3221225477)
```

Thanks in Advance,
Himanshu

Comment: What version of notes?

Comment: The version of Notes 6.5.5

Comment: This is not a programming question.  It doesn't belong on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the stack and the version number it appears to match SPR EZEL6XZ5S3. This was where Notes 6.5.3 & 6.5.5 would crash on Vista (clicking the mail icon on the welcome page).

At the time of the creation of the SPR neither versions were supported by Vista (may have changed in a later fixpack).

It was never investigated further in R6 and moved to R7/R8 where it was found to be not reproducible.

Based on this I would recommend to install the latest fixpack for that release. However R6 is end of life, so if that does not resolve the issue then the only other solution is to upgrade to a later supported release.

I see no other reports of the stack.

Comment: 6.5.5 was the only version that at least worked on some versions of Vista... the newer 6.5.6 did NOT work anymore. As you said: It was never supported and it did never run...

Comment: The os in this case is Win 7.

Comment: Also, I tried looking for the SPR number metioned above on IBM site/Google but got no result. Can you please post the link to this SPR here..@Simon

Comment: There is no public link for the SPR that I can see. Also the last Fixpack (IIRC) for R6 is 6.5.6 FP3 and was in 2008. Windows 7 was released in 2009.

Comment: I am already running 6.5.5 on win 7 64 bit w/o any issues for the last 2 years.

Comment: Not supported is not the same as not working. Just if any issues occur on an unsupported platform they are not investigated unless reproduced on a supported platform. However in your case the software is years old, so while it works there is no guarantee it will continue to do so.

Comment: To clarify my answer. I am just giving you details of the nature of the crash. To resolve the crash may be outside the scope to fix if it's a problem directly with the software.